# Checkbox states being lost after scrolling in NSTableView swift

Tags: macos, nstableview

I have this macOS app which has all the contacts listed in there.

Users can select what all suggested contacts can be updated in the app. When I deselect All checkbox in the top and just select a single/a couple of contacts and scroll down, the checkbox states are lost and they get deselected automatically. Do I need to handle any scroll event in NSTableView for swift macOS apps?

[image: Select a Single checkbox]

[image: Scroll down and scroll up]

Comment: Do you store the state of the checkboxes in your data?

Comment: Yes. But still after scrolling their states are being lost.

Comment: @Moritz, what do you mean by cell reuse? I'm saving the state in my data source and tried to scroll back and forth. I'm not redrawing the table again for this.

Comment: I think I'm not getting you. Here is the source code link. https://github.com/PriyankaBolisetty/Update-Local-contacts/blob/master/ViewController.swift The action taking place after clicking on any checkbox is checkBoxCheckedEvent().

Comment: [Table Views Reuse Rows to Increase Speed and Efficiency](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/TableViewOverview/TableViewOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH2-SW10).

Comment: Got it. Any example on how to achieve this?

Comment: In `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` get a cell view from the table view and set the values of the controls to the data values. In the action method of the check box, set the data value to the value of the check box. In your source code you don't switch the row check box on if the All checkbox is off.

Comment: Thanks Willeke, that works!!